# how to configure slf4j programatically with underlying log4j framework

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I'm develpoing a java application that uses slf4j logging with log4j framework. Is there any way to configure appenders programatically with slf4j?

Comment: check this tutorial http://rusya7.blogspot.in/2011/10/how-to-use-slf4j-with-log4j.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would strongly go against programmatically configuring SLF4J/Log4J in normal application because it is rarely appropriate to do so, and it is making SLF4J meaningless.

If you insist to do so, then you should understand, SLF4J is simply a wrapper for underlying logging library.  SLF4J itself do not have any configuration.  What you need to do is "programmatic configuration of the underlying logging framework".  If you choose to use Log4J, then search for related information for Log4J.  If you choose to use JUL, then search for JUL, etc.

Comment: oh fine then! Actually i want to pass the log file name from my program.. so only i want to configure programmatically...

Comment: If it is the case, you don't really need to do programmatical configuration.  For example, Log4J and Logback config file support replacing with System properties if I remember correctly.  So that you can define something like `${LOG_FILE_NAME}` as the filename in config, and provide it by system property (e.g. `-DLOG_FILE_NAME=mylogfile.log`)  That save you lots of unnecessary trouble to do programmatic log4j/logback configuration